# Checking URLs for HTTP code 200

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, curl

I have a text file containing a list of URLs like this:

```
http://somesite.com/some-article/
https://anothersite.fr/somepage.php?page=something
```

What I'd like to do is check which URLs return HTTP code 200 (OK) and put them in a list in another file.

How could I accomplish this using terminal? Curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
while read url ; do
    ret=$(curl -I -s "$url" -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n")
    ((ret==200)) && echo "$url" >> new_list_URL
done < list_URL
```

or POSIX mode :

```
while read url ; do
    ret=$(curl -I -s "$url" -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n")
    [ $ret -eq 200 ] && echo "$url" >> new_list_URL
done < list_URL
```

Check [man curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Thank you sputnick, but I can't seem to make it work. For some reason it doesn't output to new_list_URL. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best way, but you can use this easy-to-understand shell script too:

```bsh
while read i
do
  wget --spider $i > /dev/null 2>1
  if [ $? == 0 ]
  then
    echo $i >> validlist.txt
  fi
done
```

Run this shell script as `./wget_check.sh < urllist.txt`, where `wget_check.sh` is the script name and urllist.txt is the text file holding the URLs.

This script basically runs a `wget --spider` against all each of the URLs in the list and will add the URL to another file 'validlist.txt' if the URL returns a valid 200 OK response.

- The `--spider` option will 'crawl' through the URLs and will not download any files.
- There will be no output produced since the output will be redirected to /dev/null.
- Each `wget` will return a non-zero return value if it does not get a `200 OK response`

Answer (score 0):

I use this on-liner

```bsh
time xargs -n 1 -P 20 \
curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '"%{url_effective}","%{http_code}"\n' \
< "URLs.txt" \
| tee URLs-status_results.csv
```

And you'll get a beautiful `URLs-status_results.csv` and the time it takes.

Check [`xargs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) and [`curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) man pages.